# how to wait for js method to finish in js controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am a newbie to the aura component. I have a requirement to save current location coordinates. I don't know how to force the code to wait for coordinates. Please check the code

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){

    var lat;
    var long;
    var startPos;
    component.set('v.zoomLevel' , 18);
    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        startPos = position;
        lat = startPos.coords.latitude;
        long = startPos.coords.longitude;
        component.set('v.lat' , lat);
        component.set('v.long' , long);
        console.log('inside ---->' + lat );
        component.set('v.mapMarkersData',[
            {
            location: {
                Latitude:  lat,
                Longitude: long
                }
            }
        ]);

    }
    function error(err) {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess,error);
    var action =  component.get("c.getUserName");
    action.setParams({ latitude : lat });
}
```

when the component load

```
var action =  component.get("c.getUserName");
action.setParams({ latitude : lat });
```

the code executed first. its not  waiting  for  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess,error);` to get cordinates.

How to fix this? I need  to  get  coordinates  first successfully then I want to call the apex method (pass value of latitude and longitude)
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SFSE (Salesforce StackExchange).

This is expected because the [navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) is asynchronous and expect a callback, on your case the `geoSucess`.

So, one way to correct it is to move the 2 lines into the `geoSucess`, e.g.

```
var geoSuccess = function(position) {
    startPos = position;
    lat = startPos.coords.latitude;
    long = startPos.coords.longitude;
    component.set('v.lat' , lat);
    component.set('v.long' , long);
    console.log('inside ---->' + lat );
    component.set('v.mapMarkersData',[
        {
        location: {
            Latitude:  lat,
            Longitude: long
            }
        }
    ]);

    // Move the lines into the success callback
    var action =  component.get("c.getUserName");
    action.setParams({ latitude : lat });

}
```

Comment: how? like this??     ``` var geoSuccess = function(position) {
     var action =  component.get("c.getUserName");
    action.setParams({ latitude : lat }); startPos = position;
    lat = startPos.coords.latitude;
    long = startPos.coords.longitude;
    component.set('v.lat' , lat);
    component.set('v.long' , long);
    console.log('inside ---->' + lat );
    component.set('v.mapMarkersData',[
        {
        location: {
            Latitude:  lat,
            Longitude: long
            }
        }
    ]);

    // Move the lines into the success callback
   

} ```

Comment: Yes, you are getting in the right direction. You should move the lines that need to wait inside your `geoSucess` function (which is the callback for success), which is called after the geolocation is retrieved successfully.

Comment: I also recommend using `let` instead of `var` and declaring the variables only on the scope they are needed but this is more of general javascript practice than Aura itself.

Comment: "thanks"@Jeferson Chaves

Comment: Zafar: you are welcome, if this helped you please consider marking it as the answer.